# how to know the data type of list

Tags: java, hibernate, list, collections

here is my code,here i am taking elements into my list. but actually i have to process on my list . so necessary to know the type of list

```
public class FetchNameService {



public static Infobean fetchId() {
    Infobean infobean = new Infobean();
    Session session =  HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    String query="SELECT ifnull(max(CONVERT(substring(id,4),SIGNED) ),0) as maxId FROM infotable";
    Query name = session.createSQLQuery(query);
    List<?> list = name.list();  
    System.out.println(list.get(0));


    return infobean;
}


}
```

Comment: yes bt actual problem is with collection list

Comment: I would imagine you know the datatypes coming out of your table.

Comment: Sorry I accidentally deleted my comment "Is this Hibernate?", to which the OP responded "Yes". I have updated tag accordingly.

Comment: matter is not with database. i want to know know that it is of integer type or string typeor object type

Comment: @user3229049 Actually it matters 110%, as Hibernate has alternate approaches and ways of specifically requesting certain object types as results (e.g. Hibernate provides [`Projections`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/api/org/hibernate/criterion/Projections.html) and [`Criteria`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Criteria.html)). Without knowing what API you are using, we have no idea what `Object` types are actually being returned in the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use reflection to get the type of a class.

```
        Class clazz = list.get(0).getClass();
        System.out.println(clazz.getCanonicalName());
        System.out.println(clazz.getEnclosingClass());
        System.out.println(clazz.getSimpleName());
```

Or if you know what types of classes it could resolve to you could try something like the following:

```
        Object o = list.get(0);
        if (o instanceof String)
        {
            ...
        }
        else if (o instanceof Integer)
        {
            ...
        }
```

Comment: Excellent! Glad I could help :-). A checkmark and upvote would be much appreciated ;-).

Comment: i dont have that much of reputation

Comment: I think you can still mark an answer correct. Either way, still glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only thing you can try is instanceOf() with well-considered assumptions since `list` is of the type `List<Object>` according to [the docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Query.html#list%28%29).